# Redirecting page back to app in jquery mobile phone gap/cordova

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a payment app in jquery mobile with cordova. Where user will see a form and after filling the form they will redirect to payment gateway after successfully completing the payment they will redirect to App.

FLOW

APP -> PAYMENT GATEWAY -> APP

How will I post the data to the 3rd party API and after completing redirect back to the App?

I am new to JQM and Cordova as well as SO please help me in this regards and let me know the best way to do so.

Hope you understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova/Phonegap does not provide a way to redirect back from third party to application.

If you use Inappbrowser plugin, you just need to close the inappbrowser, once your payment process completed.

Comment: How to Post data in InAppBrowser

Comment: First, You just need to install InAppBrowser. and the send data process is same as InAppBrowser. Check this reference link

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: I installed InAppBrowser , If I have the form `<form></form>` how will I use InAppBrowser for this

Comment: Kindly refer this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html